# Has ISIS forced 1500 Yezidis and Christians into sexual slavery?

Tags: sexual-abuse, isis

In [this](http://uniraq.org/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=2373:srsg-bangura-and-srsg-mladenov-gravely-concerned-by-reports-of-sexual-violence-against-internally-displaced-persons&Itemid=605&lang=en) United Nations Assistance Mission to Iraq (UNAMI) press release it is claimed that 1500 Yazidi and Christian persons may have been forced into sexual slavery by ISIS. The source for these statements is the Special Representative of the United Nations Secretary-General for Iraq [Nickolay Mladenov](https://twitter.com/nmladenov) and the Special Representative of the Secretary-General on Sexual Violence in Conflict [Zainab Hawa Bangura](http://www.un.org/sg/management/senstaff_details.asp?smgID=174).

Does their claim hold water?

Comment: @Sklivvz Voting to re-open as it's almost four years' hence.